# Storing password protected keytool keystore to version control

Tags: security, keytool

This question has probably been asked but I don't quite understand why people suggest to not store the keystore generated using java keytool in version control. As long as the keystore as well as the keys are password protected, is there harm in storing keystore in version control?

Would encrypting the keystore along with other settings like database password, mail server passwords etc with a single key and storing these in the version control (except for the decryption key) be useful even if some is able to guess the password for keystore and keys in there?

Similar question but not clear /accepted answer:

https://superuser.com/questions/749949/should-i-add-keystore-files-to-version-control

Answer (score 0):

Passwords and other credentials are configuration aspects of the application, that are by nature environment dependent, whenever source control is meant to keep code and artifacts that are environment independent.

The-Twelve-Factor application has a good principle defined for that:
http://12factor.net/config

This is only one reason not to store credentials in the source control. The re multiple other aspects are not less important.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but beyond just "pattern" or "practice" what is the harm in storing the keystore in the version control? Would anyone having access to keystore do something without having the keystore and key passwords that could be a security issue?

Comment: There are couple of issues that I could think on top of my mind:
1) Storing environment specific credentials is bound to one environment, where in reality you always have multiple
2) The key and the password are defined at development time, meaning no segregation of duties
3) Keys are stored with the certificate that have an expiration date and hence should be reissued from time to time - source control is not the right place to manage its life-cycle